# Docker execution behavior different in command line and cmd file

Tags: windows, docker, cmd

I created the following script in cmd file :

```
docker exec my-container bash -c "stat -c '%U' /my/directory"
```

I have the following result :

```
U
```

But if I do the same in the command line directly, I have this :

```
root
```

If I replace U by A (to have rights instead ownership) :

```
docker exec my-container bash -c "stat -c '%A' /my/directory"
```

I have that with the command line :

```
drwxrwxrwx
```

And that with the cmd script

```
A
```

I don't understand why. For instance, I don't have any trouble with the following commands :

```
docker exec my-container bash -c "ls -al /"
docker exec my-container bash -c "su - -c 'ls -al /' myUser"
```

I have the expected result with the script and the command line.

Comment: [I can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/6bfe703f495a360eec073215a53edac0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is windows.
The `%U` is parsed in a batch file and the percent is removed, because there is no closing percent sign, else it would be replaced by the variable content like in `echo %PATH%`

On the command line exists [different rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7970912/463115) for the percent handling, therefore it works here.

To solve it in a batch file, just double the percent signs

```
docker exec my-container bash -c "stat -c '%%U' /my/directory"
```

Comment: So simple, I was focused on the quotes. Thank you so much